# How do I add an element to each list in a list of lists?

Tags: python

I'm stuck at a problem where I need a function that takes two arguments, one character and a lists that contains list. The function is then supposed to add that element to all the lists in the list. So if I have the arguments `"o"` and `[['tesc'], ['fo'], [1]]` the output should be `[['tesc', 'o'], ['fo', 'o'], [1, 'o']]`

Here's my code, I suspect that I'm not doing anything right as I don't get any output at all

```
def distribute(e, l):
    new_list = []
    for i in l:
        new_list.append(i)
    for e in new_list:
        new_list.append(e)
    print(new_list)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
def add_item(l, a):
   return [i+[a] for i in l]

print(add_item([['tesc'], ['fo'], [1]], "o"))
```

Output:

```
[['tesc', 'o'], ['fo', 'o'], [1, 'o']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the same variable name `'e'` in the `for-loop` and as a `function` `parameter`. Also, in this second `loop`, you want to `append` to `i` as these are the sub lists - not `append` to `new_list`.

This is why the `function` never completes as you are `looping` through each element in `new_list` but adding to `new_list` as you do so so it never ends.

Finally, I would change the `print` to `return` as you are writing a `function`:

```
def distribute(e, l):
    new_list = []
    for i in l:
        new_list.append(i)
    for i in new_list:
        i.append(e)
    return new_list
```

This will work, however it is not very `pythonic`. All the first `for-loop` is doing is creating a copy of the input list `('l')` which is necessary (in some applications) as without it, the input `list` would be modified as `lists` are `immutable`.

However, you could get rid of this `loop` altogether by just copying the `list` with a  `slice`. This would make your function more succinct:

```
def distribute(e, l):
    new_list = l[:]
    for i in new_list:
        i.append(e)
    return new_list
```

And of course, if you do not care if the `list` parsed into the `function` is modified, you can not bother making a copy of it:

```
def distribute(e, l):
    for i in l:
        i.append(e)
    return l
```

Answer (score 1):

You're making things too complicated:

```
def distribute(e, l):
    for sublist in l:
        sublist.append(e)

    print(l)

distribute("o", [['tesc'], ['fo'], [1]])
```

Output:

```
[['tesc', 'o'], ['fo', 'o'], [1, 'o']]
```